What is Binds for? Whats the difference with mounting a shared folder?
Upon inspect my docker container info shows:
"HostConfig": {
    "Binds": [
        "/opt/myconfig:/run/db_config:rw"
    ],

I suspect this works as a mounting volumes with:
-v mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

But, I need to understand the difference between -v and whatever cmd created the Binds. Which cmd as -v could create the Binds entry?

The -v option on docker run can map both a docker volume or a host directory.
If the thing you're mapping is a directory or a file, docker creates a bind mount. If it's not, then docker creates a volume mapping.
For example,
docker run -v ./data:/data myimage

creates a bind mount, whereas
docker run -v data:/data myimage

creates a volume mount.
You can also be more explicit by using the --mount option instead. Using --mount is recommended, but as it's more verbose, most people use the -v option.
In your example, what created the bind mount would be an option like this
-v /opt/myconfig:/run/db_config

Mounts are read/write per default, so there's no reason to specify that.
You can read more here.

-v or  --volume: This option is used by users in the docker run command to set up a bind mount at the time of the container run, mapping a host path to a container path.
Binds in HostConfig: This only visible when you inspect a container, shows the actual bind mounts applied to the container as configured by -v or --mount or --volume. It’s not a command but a record of the mount configuration. it is recorded as part of the docker image build
If we summerise, -v will create the mount, and Binds will reflect it in Docker’s internal configuration.

"HostConfig": { "Binds": [ ... ] } is also part of the Docker HTTP API.
